# Crystal Report Formula If then else

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to find the way how to remove 2 digit decimals in field purchaseorder.UPRI when purchaseorder.CUR = "IDR". The way that I have tried does not help me to solve myproblem
How do I fix it ? Does anyone here could help me to solve the problem ?
Here is my code;

```
IF{purchaseorder.CUR} = "IDR" 
IF(ROUND({purchaseorder.UPRI},0) <> {purchaseorder.UPRI}) THEN
(
    2
)
ELSE
(
    0
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't try it right now, but try these options and tell me if it worked:

```
if {purchaseorder.CUR} = "IDR" 
then Truncate({purchaseorder.UPRI})
```

Comment: I am sorry for being late to reply your comment in advance, I have tried it for both of them but it does not work for me

Comment: I'm sorry, the first one was really wrong, now I could test it. Truncate turns the number to integer, without rounding. Isn't that what you want? Example: 1234.56 -> 1234

Comment: thank you for your support, it really works by adding round brackets () like this if ({purchaseorder.CUR} = "IDR") then Truncate({purchaseorder.UPRI}). Thank you so much friend